# Create a view model with a parameter in the constructor (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, window, viewmodel

I'm writing a code in MVVM.

I Have a WinForm that will call a method that will open a new window(WPF window).
The view window should show bank account details.(Grid with all the transaction of a bank customer).

```
MyBankAccountWindow win = new MyBankAccountWindow();
win.ViewModel.Initialize(BankAccountID)
win.ShowDialog()
```

I'm using a view model that will expose that transaction details of the customer.
The data initalizing will be based on the customer so I need to create the ViewModel based on the customerID.

My ViewModel been declared at the xaml so it been initialize at the window creation process.
For now i'n using a property of the ViewModel at the window code behind but I don't like that approach because:

1. I created a ViewModel that is not ready to be used until Initialize didn't take place by the caller. (In the code that create the window)
2. I have a property of the view model in my window code behind.

What is the approach that I should take to avoid that?

Comment: MEF, MEF, MEF... Did I mention MEF?

Comment: @HighCore no I missed that, can you say what that was again pls. OP -> Unity is also a great DI Manager. Worth a read http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/04/01/unity-vs-mef.aspx

Comment: Saying that for a simple application, http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/ and it's examples come with a built in `SimpleIoC` that will teach you the basics and sufficiently solve your current problem.

Comment: I edit the question to be more clear...

Comment: I upticked the Unity comments because that's the way to go, *BUT* you might be able to use a Lazy<> initializer that specifies a factory.  I know it's very anti-pattern, but might work for you